# png images not uploaded to server using codeigniter image upload library

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

I use codeigniter upload library to upload images  to server .
It works fine for all other image types but I cannot upload png images to online server. Also it works fine in my local server for all image types including png. Problem exists only in server for png images

below is my controller function

```
function insertpartner(){

    $data['success'] = "";
    $data['error'] = "";
    $this->load->library('form_validation', 'session');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="errorMsg">', '</div>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtTitle', ' title', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        redirect('sitemanager/partners/addpartners');
    } else {
        if (isset($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] != "") {

            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/partnerlogo/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|bmp|jpeg';
            //$config['max_size'] = '20000';
            //$config['max_width'] = '800';
            //$config['max_height'] = '700';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);   //--------------- Loading image uploading library------------------

            $configThumb = array();
            $configThumb['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $configThumb['source_image'] = '';
            $configThumb['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $configThumb['width'] = 140;
            $configThumb['height'] = 70;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');        //--------------- Loading image_library for resizing the image-----

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                $data['error'] = "<div class='error'>" . $this->upload->display_errors() . "</div>";
                $data['success'] = "";
                $data['category'] = $this->m_adminlogin->showcategories();
                redirect('sitemanager/partners/addpartners',$data);
            } else {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $imgPath = $data['file_name'];
                $config['remove_space'] = TRUE;
                $configThumb['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
                $configThumb['new_image'] = "./uploads/partnerlogo/thumbs/" . $data['file_name'];
                $this->image_lib->initialize($configThumb);
                if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                    $data['error'] = "<div class='error'>Thumbnail creation failed.</div>";
                    $data['success'] = "";
                    redirect('sitemanager/partners/addpartners',$data);
                }
            }
        } 
        //$url=$this->input->post('txturl');
        //$url="http://".$url;
        $partnerdetails = array(
            'categoryId' => $this->input->post('selCategory'),
           /* 'intfeatured' => $featured,*/
            'name' => $this->input->post('txtTitle'),
            'logo' => $imgPath,
            'url'  =>$this->input->post('txturl')
        );


        if ($this->m_partners->insertpartners($partnerdetails))
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', "<div class='success'>Successfully added  Details.</div>");
        else
            $this->session->set_flashdata('failure', "<div class='error'>Try after sometimes.</div>");
        redirect("sitemanager/partners/viewpartners", $data);
    }
   }
```

Comment: Try to print error of image_lib and also from upload. Also have a look at your logs

Comment: What is your CI version, please try adding wild card to the `$config['allowed_types'] = '*';` If your upload works, then there is a problem in MIME types.

Comment: i solved the problem changes the problem http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/204725/P15